# Anchor can't find headings

Tags: tfs, markdown

I have headings in all of my TFS 2018 Wiki documentation but I can't seem to link to those headings. If I have a document at `/foo/bar` and a heading in the `bar` document called `# 1.3 Hello World` I would expect my link to be `[Hello World](/foo/bar#1.3-Hello-World)` but when I click on that link it doesn't take me to the heading. Instead, it just takes me to the document itself.

When I look at the URL, it shows `&anchor=1.3-Hello-World` but that anchor is not scrolled to. In this example, I have to scroll pretty far in order to find the heading. How can I link directly to a heading in TFS 2018 Wiki markdown?

Comment: Are you sure the slug is actually `1.3-Hello-World`? There is no standard way to convert a header to an slug. In fact, in standard Markdown its not done at all. Have you checked? Try using your browser's "view source" function (or "inspect") to confirm what id is actually set on your header. As long as the two don't match, it will never work.

Comment: I will check, this worked when the documentation was in standard markdown stored in my TFS git repo. TFS would render it correctly when browsing them in the code browser, and the anchor links worked. Not sure if the wiki uses a different parser than the source code viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe anchor links are supported in **TFS 2018** Wiki. I can't get it to work and I find no evidence it is (presently) supported.

Much or all of the material cited here refers to a different product, **Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)** Wiki. Follow a link and notice the somewhat obscure top, left-hand (product) drop down list (*Visual Studio Team Services*). Change it to *TFS 2018* and notice that the reference material (documentation) changes.

**TFS 2018** tends to be a bit behind the hosted VSTS product. I would not be surprised support is coming in a future release.

Comment: "Link to headings within a page" was released for TFS On-premises. You'll need the July 10 (2018) update.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts#link-to-headings-within-a-page

Comment: why did you link to VSTS release notes?  Did you think they were TFS On-premises release notes?  If not, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Grank, upon reflection, "TFS 2018 tends to be a bit behind the hosted VSTS product". Consequently I would not expect the feature in TFS 2018 until sometime after its VSTS announcement. I did not find the TFS 2018 release note to link.

Answer (score 1):

> Once the [Wiki Git repository is provisioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/wiki-create-repo?view=vsts) for your team
>   project, a new page opens in which you can specify a title and add
>   content. This is a side by side edit and preview experience that will
>   allow you to edit the page and preview the content as you type.
>
> You author pages using **markdown format**. Also, you can use the
>   format pane for rich-text formatting and to insert images,
>   attachments, and links.

WiKi is also using markdown format, details please refer: [Syntax guidance for Markdown files, widgets, wikis, and pull request comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#headers)

About the Link part please take a look at below format:

***Supported links for Wiki:***

- Absolute path of Wiki pages: `[text to
  display](/parent-page/child-page)`
- URL: `[text to display](http://address.com)`

***Anchor links***

Within Markdown files, anchor IDs are assigned to all headings when rendered as HTML. The ID is the heading text, with the spaces replaced by dashes (-) and all lower case. In general, the following conventions:

- Punctuation marks and leading white spaces within a file name are
  ignored
- Upper case letters are converted to lower
- Spaces between letters are converted to dashes (-).

More details please refer [**Anchor links**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#anchor-links)

Comment: Looking at the `id` in the HTML,, it is prefixed with `user-content` for some reason. So my id actually looks like `user-content-1.1-hello-world`. If I link to the heading using `/foo/bar#user-content-1.1-hello-world` it still will not link to the correct heading. However, if I modify the URL in my browser so it ends with `&anchor=user-content-1.1-hello-world` it navigates to the heading just fine. It seems like the markdown is not generating the correct url.

Comment: The URL that gets generated is `https://tfsserver.com/collection/test/_wiki/wikis/test.wiki?wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster&pagePath=%2Ffoo%2Fbar&anchor=user%20content%201.2%20hello%20world`. If I modify the anchor in this url so that it is not HTML encoded, it works fine.

Comment: After more testing, if I use a single word for my heading it is discovered. If I use multiple words, then the hyphen becomes URL encoded. Browsing to the URL encoded anchor fails. If I replace the URL encoded %20 with a hyphen in the browser URL bar, then the heading is discovered. It appears to be an issue with TFS wikis handling URL encoding on the anchors.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Thanks for the sharing, always better when you fixed it yourself, as you understood how it works. Not sure about this is an issue or by designed. You could submit a case to [TFS  DeveloperCommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html), TFS PM and developers will kindly review it. Appreciate for your contribution.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT: Question is for on-premises TFS 2018 Wiki. At least the provided "Anchor links" link is for Visual Studio Team Services, a different product. If you navigate the link and select "TFS 2018" instead it no longer states that "anchor IDs are assigned to all headings".