# How to set an anchor in Markdown File

Tags: html, tfs, markdown

I want to set an anchor in a .md file. The file is in the Team Foundation Server but the tag `<a name="anchor"></a>` does not work. Are there any other possibilities to set an anchor in a .md file?

I already tried the following:

Link to an anchor

```markdown
[Question 22](answers.md#answer22)
```

Setting an anchor

```
<a name="answer22"></a> This is an answer for Question 22
```

The result is that clicking on "Question 22" the file answers.md is opened successfully but isn't "hopping" to Question 22. Furthermore the tag `<a name="answer22"><a/>` doesn't seem to be recognized as Code in the md. File in the TFS. If I open the File answer22.md and look at the preview (in TFS you can switch between "contents", "preview", "history" etc.) the tag is not hidden and you can see it in the preview as if it is just plain text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in [Microsofts basic Markdown guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#anchor-links), anchors are generated for every heading.

Just place your answer below a heading.

**questions.md**

```markdown
[Question22](./answers.md#answer-22)
```

**answers.md**

```markdown
## Answer 22

The answer is 42
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it and it worked out.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. 
it just works for headings doesn't it? So there is no way to make an anchor in a table cell?

Comment: I am glad I could help you. As far as I know and as mentioned in the linked documentation: **Yes** - this only works for headings

Answer (score 3):

### Common Markdown cross-references

See the [Markdown Guide, Extended Syntax: Linking to Heading IDs](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#linking-to-heading-ids).

This markdown:

```markdown
[Heading ID](#heading-id)
```

Should be rendered to following HTML link by most supported engines:

```html
<a href="#heading-id">Heading ID</a>
```

This again might reference the page-fragment (anchor) named `heading-id` either within the same page but also on other pages relatively (`/other-page#heading-id`) or files within the same namespace/folder (denoted by `./other-file.md/#heading-id`).

### Supported in TFS

From the docs [TFS 2018: Basic Markdown Guidance, Anchor links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=tfs-2018#anchor-links):

> You can also reference headings within another Markdown file:
>
> `[text to display](./target.md#heading-id)`

> In wiki, you can also reference heading in another page:
>
> `[text to display](/page-name#section-name)`

To reference other Markdown files or wiki pages it is important to know how the **anchor names** (here `heading-id` or `section-name`) are assigned from the headings there: the *slug*.

#### From headings to slugs

The text of the headings serves as anchor-name in *slug* form. Slugs are generated from any text by following these rules:

- punctuation marks and leading white spaces (also within a file name) are ignored
- all lowercase
- one or many consecutive spaces converted to a single hyphen

#### See also

- Similar question [Anchor can't find headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803938/anchor-cant-find-headings), answered by TFS gold-badge decorated PatrickLu-MSFT.
- Microsoft Developer Community, [Azure DevOps Server (TFS), search for "anchor"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOpsServerTFS?q=anchor)

Answer (score 1):

In Pandoc Markdown you can set anchors on arbitrary spans inside a paragraph using syntax `[span]{#anchor}`, e.g.:

```markdown
[This is an answer for question 22]{#answer-22}
```

And then reference it as usual: `[Question 22](#answer-22)`.

If you want to reference a whole paragraph then formally it's not possible but you can make a simple hack adding an *empty* span right in the beginning of the paragraph:

```markdown
[]{#answer-22}
Paragraph text.
```